# What is the solution for Highcharts hover

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I draw an area chart using highchart jquery plug-in. 3 arrays needs to be passed to draw chart through AJAX call. 1st array data for x-axis. 2nd array data for Y-axis.3rd array has string value which needs to be passed into hover(max) along with y-axis value. Each array has 90 values. is it possible to show third array into hover?
Could you please any one help me out?

```
$('#divcontainer').highcharts({

        chart: {

            type: 'area'
        },
        credits: {
  enabled: false },plotOptions: {
         area: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function () {

                    return false; // <== returning false will cancel the default action
                }
            }
        ,
        showInLegend: true
    }
}, title: {
        text: 'Chart',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: '',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
          labels:{rotation: rot, x:-20},
           categories: data[0]

      },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Status'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value:0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip:{
         enabled: true,
         formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/><b>' + 'Status: ' + this.y + '</b>';}},

series: [{
        name: 'Status',
        data: data[1]
        }]
});
```

`data[0] is 1st array, data[1] is 2nd array, and data[2] is 3rd array`. These are the arrays from the ajax call.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some of the code you have for constructing this chart? Questions without any source code can be difficult to answer properly.

Comment: When you say "hover", do you mean "tooltip"?

Comment: @aus_lacy yes it's tool tip

Comment: @kenster I have added code.Please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like:

```
tooltip:{
         enabled: true,
         formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/><b>' + 'Status: ' + this.y + '</b>' + data[2][this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )];
         }
},
```

Notice the part with `data[2][this.series.data.indexOf( this.point )]`.

Comment: where will i add data[2] in series jquery?i didn't add data[2] in series highchart.Please let me Know

Comment: Now I understand what you wrote

Comment: hello @aus_lacy sir, I have another doubt.1st array data for x-axis has 30 values. 2nd array data for Y-axis has 90 values.But i want to plot chart single x-axis value to 3 Y-axis values.Is it possible?,Please let me know If it is possible

Comment: Above comment isn't possible.I have 90 values for x-axis.i have 90 values for y-axis.i want show 30 values in x-axis and 90 floats in y-axis